Connect-AzAccount not working from Gitlab yaml
I am trying to connect to Azure subscription using Connect-AzAccount with Service Principal. I am using this method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-11.4.0#example-3-connect-to-azure-using-a-service-principal-account. I have written a gitlab-ci.yml where it should connect to azure and run a powershell script. Pipeline is running on a Windows runner with Powershell and Az modules installed. The pipeline fails when Connect-AzAccount runs with error.

Exception : An error occurred while sending the request

I am running this in my client's network. Setting up PROXY as well before running.
gitlab-ci.yml
before-script:
 - $env:HTTPS_PROXY = "https://xx.xx.xx.xxx"
 - $env:HTTPS_PROXY_CERT = "C:\folders\cert.crt"
  - $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "xxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
  - $TenantId = 'xxxxxx'
  - $ApplicationId = 'xxxxxx'
  - $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList      $ApplicationId, $SecurePassword
  - Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential

Ran all of these commands directly from powershell in Windows runner, it works fine. However same commands fails when run from gitlab ci.

Refer this link for logging with SP in gitlab

@VenkatV this speaks about GitHub. My problem is connecting to Azure from Gitlab using Connect-AzAccount with Service Principal.


Connect-AzAccount not working from Gitlab yaml

Make sure to verify that there are no network restrictions or firewalls blocking connections from the GitLab pipeline to Azure
You can use below .yml and powershell file to run Connect-AzAccount  with a Service Principal in GitLab.
.gitlab-ci.yml
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
    
    Job:
        stage: deploy
        script:
            - pwsh ./powershell.ps1


powershell.ps1
    Install-Module Az -Force
    $TenantId = '22xxxxxxxx-4005-acfb-9bbfa7d40283'
    $ApplicationId = 'bf7e1xxxxx9-10f90c4811d2'
    $SecurePassword = 'yYA8Q~xxxxx-HKNYX~1S-vgAJVa.n'
    $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $SecurePassword -AsPlainText -Force
    $pscredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecurePassword
    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $TenantId
    New-AzResourceGroup -Name RG01 -Location "South Central US"

Here is my repository with .yml and PowerShell files.

After running the pipeline, it successfully connected to Azure and created a resource group.

Resource group has been created successfully.


Thanks @VenkatV for the files. I tired them on my personal subscription and it works. However, the same fails on client network. On client Gitlab server is hosted on AWS. Now I believe that there is some firewall restriction from Gitlab to Azure. On the other note, az cli commands like az login --Service-Principal works fine from same gitlab pipelines.

Are you facing issue with only Powershell not with Azure Cli? If that is case,you can use Az login as there is no difference btwn azlogin and connect-azaccount. Hope this helps to resolve your query.

Actually I am migrating pipelines from ADO to Gitlab. These pipelines use powershell scripts which has Azure Powershelll commands. If I use az login then those scripts does not work. Throws error to connect to azure using Connect-AzAccount. So instead of updating the scripts to use az cli commands I want to connect using Connect-AzAccount. I even tried to connect with az login and then set the context in scripts but that also does not work.

If that is case, check with client network team for allow the access from GitLab to Azure.
